# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing entity from NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nspredicate

I'm having this weird issue when updating my app from iOS7 to iOS9.
This code works fine on iOS7 and iOS8 but when using iOS9, I've got this error message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when trying to get the value of one property.

**This is the code**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Claim")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userType == %d", role)

do
    {
        let retValue = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Claim]

        if (retValue.count > 1)
        {
            for cEntity in retValue
            {
                print("--")
                print("cEntity.claimID: \(cEntity.claimID)")
                print("cEntity.dateCreated: \(cEntity.dateCreated)")  <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
             }
         }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error!!!")
    }
```

**On iOS7 and iOS8 it prints:**

```
--
cEntity.claimID: 1962872
cEntity.dateCreated: 2015-04-12 22:46:30 +0000
--
cEntity.claimID: 1962839
cEntity.dateCreated: 2015-04-12 22:36:33 +0000
```

**On iOS9 it prints**

```
--
cEntity.claimID: 1962872
```

What am I doing wrong?
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: where the app is crash? 2 line?

Comment: @MihirOza it crashes when accessing cEntity.dateCreated. Just that line where I wrote <-- ESC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: What does it print when run in iOS 7 & 8?

Comment: @DanielT. on iOS8 it prints `cEntity.claimID: 1962839
cEntity.dateCreated: 2015-04-12 22:36:33 +0000`

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. You should make a project with the minimum necessary to reproduce this bug and report it to Apple. Good luck.

Comment: @DanielT. Will do if I really can't find a workaround. Thanks anyway

Comment: The workaround is to not use CoreData with Swift... They don't get along well. 

Answer (score 0):

The bad access is due to optional and non optional values in attribute.
The attribute does not have any value i.e. nil and you have declared it as non optional. Thats why it try to access that value which is not allocated in memory.

To solve this:
1. Open core data model. And declare Claim attribute property as
    option type like dateCreated?

2. Open "Claim" Entity.
3. Check Optional in Attribute property [image]

this will set nil value if value is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the attribute Optional is already checked for the property dateCreated.

Comment: Then check your code EXC_BAD_ACCESS only comes when you are accessing that value which is not in memory or released.

Comment: Wait, you have the value marked as optional? The make it optional in your Claim class. Maybe that will fix it.